# Connecting to apache tomcat from outside

Tags: apache, tomcat

I'm new to these forums and I hope I don't ask a stupid question. I've seen answers to my problem several times on the net, but it never worked for me.

So basically I installed tomcat 8 on a Debian 8.1 distant server, and I would like to simply connect to that server. But when I try to connect to MY_SERVER_IP:8080 in my web browser, I get a "This site can’t be reached" message, instead of the "It works !" page that I should get.

When I type this code on my ssh software (Putty) :

```
telnet MY_SERVER_IP 8080
GET /
```

The server sends an html page, with somewhere written "If you're seeing this, you've successfully installed Tomcat. Congratulations!". So it really looks like my server was properly installed, but that I just can't access it from outside. We also checked which ports are open, using the ssh software, and the port 8080 is actually open for IPv6 addresses only...

I tried to remove the "address" attribute from the "Connector" tag in /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.13/conf/server.xml, and I also tried to add address="0.0.0.0" to it. I tried to add `JAVA_OPTS= $JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses` to the catalina.sh startup script, as well as writing it in a new `TOMCAT_HOME/bin/setenv.sh` script. None of this worked.

Is there a way to fix my issue ? Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT : after I call the instruction `netstat -pln`, my ssh software returns this (some of it is in french so let me know if you need some translation):

```
Connexions Internet actives (seulement serveurs)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat        PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15594/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15624/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15594/named
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      19285/java
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      15594/named
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      15624/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      15594/named
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      19285/java
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           15594/named
udp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                                15594/named
Sockets du domaine UNIX actives(seulement serveurs)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Chemin
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16166    1/systemd           /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     811      1/systemd           /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     815      1/systemd           /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     25198    1/systemd           /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     34670    1/systemd           /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5612     1/systemd           /run/acpid.socket
```

So unless I'm mistaken, it looks like the server is listening only to IPv6 addresses on the port 8080.

EDIT 3 : I added the two JAVA_OPTS arguments about IP4 again, restarted my tomcat, reran the netstat, and did `ps -ef | grep java`. Here is the result :

```
root@ns397627:~# netstat -pln
Connexions Internet actives (seulement serveurs)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Adresse locale          Adresse distante        Etat        PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2532/java
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15594/named
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15624/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:953           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15594/named
tcp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                    LISTEN      15594/named
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      15624/sshd
tcp6       0      0 ::1:953                 :::*                    LISTEN      15594/named
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*                           15594/named
udp6       0      0 ::1:53                  :::*                                15594/named
Sockets du domaine UNIX actives(seulement serveurs)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   PID/Program name    Chemin
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     16166    1/systemd           /run/systemd/private
unix  2      [ ACC ]     SEQPACKET  LISTENING     811      1/systemd           /run/udev/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     815      1/systemd           /run/systemd/journal/stdout
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     25198    1/systemd           /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     34670    1/systemd           /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5612     1/systemd           /run/acpid.socket
root@ns397627:~# ps -ef | grep java
tomcat8   2532     1 99 10:15 ?        00:00:20 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/var/lib/tomcat8/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/share/tomcat8/endorsed -classpath /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/var/lib/tomcat8 -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/tomcat8-tomcat8-tmp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root      2557  2016  0 10:15 pts/4    00:00:00 grep java
```

Comment: This could be any number of things in the network and since you demonstrated the tomcat was working, its probably a question for serverfault. Can you check the tomcat is actually listening on an external, accessible interface? try [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/357323/how-can-i-list-my-open-ports-on-debian)

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for your answer. I already tried what you suggested and it's actually what made me think that my server works only for IPv6 addresses (though I'm not sure because I don't have much knowledge on this point). I anyway edited my post and added the answer of my ssh software when I type the instruction from the link you gave me, if you could help me to interpret that it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Add the two JAVA_OPTS arguments about IP4 again, restart the tomcat, rerun the netstat, and do `ps -ef | grep java` and post the result in your question

Comment: Where exactly should I add those JAVA_OPTS arguments ? In a new TOMCAT_HOME/bin/setenv.sh script, or elsewhere ?

Comment: That should do it - https://serverfault.com/a/571436 - use the `ps -ef | grep java` once its restarted to check that the command line has the option set. If so, then use the netstat to see if its bound to the ipv4 interface

Comment: @spacepickle I tried to follow your instructions (even though I'm not sure that I put the JAVA_OPTS arguments at the right place), and edited my question with the new results. It still shows "tcp6" so I still it didn't work, but maybe I did it wrong. I put my JAVA_OPTS argument in a new setenv.sh script, in the /etc/tomcat8/bin directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a default install of tomcat8 on debian jessie (8.7), you can force tomcat to use IPv4 addresses with the following in your setenv.sh file:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses"
```

Note the use of double quotes around the value part of the statement.

The following command will append to your current setenv.sh file in the correct location (remember to remove the original setenv.sh if you have JAVA_OPTS set there already)

```
echo 'JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses"' >> /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/setenv.sh
```

Comment: I actually found by myself where I should put this setenv.sh file, it was in /usr/share/tomcat8/bin/setenv.sh, because it's the value of CATALINA_HOME... Sorry I'm really not good at this stuff. I edited my question, and indeed now the result of the netstat is different, though the http://MY_SERVER_IP:8080/ page still won't display "It works !" so I still have a problem somewhere. Thanks for answering me anyway, it's really helpful !

Comment: @ntyss I dont mean to be cheeky but can I just check that you mean that you are using the actual IP address of the server (like 114.116.2.3 or something) and not actually MY_SERVER_IP?

Comment: Haha yeah I of course use an IPv4 address, and not MY_SERVER_IP. I actually also tried on the windows command prompt to connect to my server, using telnet, on the port 8080.

Comment: @ntyss Try installing apache2 and see if you can get to port 80 on the machine. If this doesnt work Id have to start asking about hosting providers and where you are trying to hit this from. Thats why this is not an ideal question for stackoverflow - we've wandered out of a programming question

Comment: @ntyss Id delete that comment now - I can hit the page - you should have seen my request come in - please dont post that here :)

Comment: Wait, do you mean you can access the page on your side ?? Anyway, I deleted my comment. I just installed apache2 on the server btw.

Comment: @ntyss yes I'm hoping you have logging setup and saw my request. Try hitting it from a mobile device or something that is unlikely to have a firewall in front of it. If you have Apache2 running try hitting port 80

Comment: No I don't have that setup. But omg yes... It works from my phone, using phone data. I guess it's the net from the building where I work which was blocking... Thanks for your help anyway, it really saved the day.